# How to remove bottom border from last-child

Tags: css

I have this style for the opencart category menu:

```
#menu .dropdown-inner a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1f90bb;
}
```

And I am trying to remove the bottom border:

```
#menu.dropdown-inner a li:last-child { 
  border-bottom: none; 
}
```

But it's not working. Please help!

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/u0m8nb73)

Comment: border-bottom: none !important;

Comment: Tried that, not working.

Comment: #menu .dropdown-inner a li:last-child {    space issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second style so that the a is inside the li:

```
    .... li:last-child a { 
border-bottom: none !important; 
}
```

Comment: Please see an example I just added.

Comment: I edited my answer for your new information. If you do this in your js fiddle, it works how you'd expect.

Comment: You're my HERO! Thanks.